# ddply slow when used to aggregate by date over factor variable

Tags: r

I am having a terrible time running 'ddply' over two variables in what seems like it should be a simple command.

Sample data (df):

```
Brand    Day     Rev     RVP              
  A      1        2535.00  195.00 
  B      1        1785.45  43.55 
  C      1        1730.87  32.66 
  A      2        920.00   230.00
  B      2        248.22   48.99 
  C      3        16466.00 189.00      
  A      1        2535.00  195.00 
  B      3        1785.45  43.55 
  C      3        1730.87  32.66 
  A      4        920.00   230.00
  B      5        248.22   48.99 
  C      4        16466.00 189.00
```

I am using the command:

```
df2<-ddply(df, .(Brand, Day), summarize, Rev=mean(Rev), RVP=sum(RVP))
```

My dataframe has about 2600 observations, and there are 45 levels of "Brand" and up to 300 levels of "Day" (which is coded using 'difftime').

I am able to easily use 'ddply' when simply grouping by "Day," but when I also try to group by "Brand," my computer freezes up.

Thoughts?

Comment: ddply is just slow, especially when there are many small groups.  try data.table with 'by' instead.

Comment: Are there any tutorials you could point me to?

Comment: We would end up pointing you to the same tutorials that Google will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read through the help pages for `aggregate`, `by`, `ave`, and `tapply`, paying close attention to the types of the arguments each one of them expects and the names of the arguments as well. Then run all of the examples or `demo()`. The main thing @hadley did with pkg:plyr and reshape/reshape2 was  to impose some degree of regularity, but it was at the expense of speed. I do understand why he did it, especially when I try to use the `base::reshape` function, but also when I forget as I repeatedly do, which of these requires a list, which requires the FUN= argument label, which needs `interaction()` for the grouping variable, .... since they are all somewhat different.

```
> aggregate(df[3:4], df[1:2], function(d) mean(d) )
   Brand Day       Rev    RVP
1      A   1  2535.000 195.00
2      B   1  1785.450  43.55
3      C   1  1730.870  32.66
4      A   2   920.000 230.00
5      B   2   248.220  48.99
6      B   3  1785.450  43.55
7      C   3  9098.435 110.83
8      A   4   920.000 230.00
9      C   4 16466.000 189.00
10     B   5   248.220  48.99
```