# Run a function inside data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

Hi I have some data in data.table format in R and I need to run some function.

Let say I have a data.table called A with columns, "name" "height", "weight".

I want to run some function, i.e. linear regression within data.table and store the coefficients, RMSE into the table results.

```
A[, .(beta = lm(height ~ weight)$coefficients[2], RMSE = 
     as.numeric(sqrt(crossprod(lm(height 
     ~ weight)$residuals)/(length(lm(height ~ weight)$residuals)- 
     (length(coef(lm(height ~ weight)))-1)))*100),
     by=.(name)]
```

My question: Is there a way to save the lm(height ~ weight) result as an object and then access this object's data so data.table don't need to run the lm function like 4 times in here?

This runs but it is a bit too slow compared to me using foreach and loop over "name" as I have millions rows of data.

Thanks.

Comment: This does beg the question of "tidy" work (referencing much of the tidyverse) but with the speed/efficiencies of `data.table`. Interesting, I'll be looking for a good discussion/education on this!

Comment: Currently if I run the lm function with getting the coefficients only, it takes 2 seconds. If I need to run lm function 4 times to calculate RMSE and it takes 12 seconds! I am so used to data.table syntax now, but as tidyverse is growing so big I might need to learn both!

Comment: Related: [data.table: anonymous function in j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898162/data-table-anonymous-function-in-j). Use `{ }`, an anonymous body in `j`. Fill it with whatever function you wish (e.g. `lm`!). Finally, wrap desired return variables in `list( )` (or the dot alias `.( )`).

Comment: See the examples in the answer here: [Using data.table to create a column of regression coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13906196/1851712), e.g. the second where `{ }` is used and an 'auxiliary` object is first created, then columns returned in `list(...)`.

Comment: Also `lm()` is slow-ish as it does too much -- `lm.fit()` is a simpler alternative but you may then have to compute your own residuals.  And you probably don't want to run `lm()` multiple times just for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

By using anonymous body as suggested by Henrik, I am able to speed up the process!

```
A[, {model <- lm(height ~ weight)
       BETA <- model$coefficient[2]
       RMSE <- as.numeric(sqrt(crossprod(model$residuals)/(length(model$residuals)- 
               (length(coef(model))-1)))*100)

       list(BETA = BETA, RMSE = RMSE)
       },
 by = .(name)]
```

Apparently, an anonymous body (lambda) does not require a name and it is like "run once and forget". Inside this lambda, the `lm()` function is ran once (per group), and the result stored in an object.

We can then extract the required data from the model object and lastly `list()` is provided to let `j` convert the extracted data into columns.

Many thanks!